# selecting index change of dropdownlist related prblm

Tags: c#, .net

i have a 3 tables: Section,Class and Student...now i want to loading the studentName on the dropdownlist based on selection Class with selecting section in dropdown list[Here Section Field,Class Field will b select by dropdownlist and StudentName also show in to the dropdownlist]

Here is my Table preview

**SectionEnty**

```
Id,SectionTitle,Capacity
```

**ClassEntry**

```
Id,ClassTitle,SectionId
```

**StudentInfo**

```
Id,FullName,ClassId,Section
```

it will b very helpful for me. If any one help me at this situation because i am all ready tried but its not working because of multiple index handling.

Comment: can you be a tad more specific please ??? !!!

Comment: Hei Ted..actually i have three dropdownlist such as classdropdown,sectiondropdown and Studentname dropdown.Now i want to retrieve the student name from StudentTable acording to selecting class and section from dropdownlist...

Answer (score 0):

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="classdropdown" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="classdropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="sectiondropdown" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="sectiondropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="studentnamedropdown" runat="server" />
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.LoadClassDropdown();
    }
}

// set initial values
private void LoadClassDropdown()
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id,SectionTitle FROM SectionEnty", "your connection string"))
    {    
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();

            classdropdown.DataSource = ds;
            classdropdown.DataValueField = "Id";
            classdropdown.DataTextField = "SectionTitle";
            classdropdown.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void classdropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id,ClassTitle FROM ClassEntry WHERE SectionId = @SectionId", "your connection string")
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SectionId", sectiondropdown.SelectedValue));

        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();

            sectiondropdown.DataSource = ds;
            sectiondropdown.DataValueField = "Id";
            sectiondropdown.DataTextField = "ClassTitle";
            sectiondropdown.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void sectiondropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id,FullName FROM StudentInfo WHERE ClassId = @ClassId", "your connection string"))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClassId", classdropdown.SelectedValue));

        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();

            studentnamedropdown.DataSource = ds;
            studentnamedropdown.DataValueField = "Id";
            studentnamedropdown.DataTextField = "FullName";
            studentnamedropdown.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Now your studentnamedropdown contains the list for the selected class and section.

Any questions, let me know...

Comment: Hei Ted Thanks for your effort on my query.I allready apply your mechanism but there is an error arise... at this point "               private void LoadClassDropdown()
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
//error[Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]//  da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select Id,SectionTitle    From SectionEntry";"

Comment: hmm it looks like da isn't initialized. my bad. check the post again, i have changed the using statement to include the sqlcommand and sqlconnection n the contructor

Comment: Ted thanks for ur reply..i also try as u say...but there is another problem arise... /**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)***               i m trying to fix  this...but you also give me the Hints about How u write connection string on ur machine...thn it will a more easy for me...

Comment: have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/ click on the link according to the sql server version (2005, 2008 etc) and it will give you an example for each case according to your sql server